# Buffering algorithm

Tags: distance, coordinates, buffer, algorithm

Does anyone know the algorithm of buffering?

I had difficulty in drawing buffers.

So I tried many values to acquire 1km buffer.
I found value 0.008966 produces 1km buffer.

Then I calculated inverse number.  111.5324 was the result.

Circumference of the earth is 40077km.
1 rad is 57.29578.
40077*57.29578/360=6378.4527

6378.4527 was divided by the 111.5324.
Answer was 57.18923 .

I am sure there are errors in the calculation, but the final result was close to 1 rad.

Perhaps a squared value was used.

Comment: Drawing buffers where? What program are you referring to? 
Why are you calculating values related to the size of the earth?

Comment: Degrees latitude are the same distance apart everywhere but degrees longitude are closer together at higher latitudes.

Answer (score 3):

your coordinates are probably in lat/long with degrees as a unit.

therefore, along meridians or near the equator, one degree is approximately 111km (circumference/360).

note that this will change depending on the distance to the equator. A good practice is to use a local projected coordinate system that is appropriate for your location in order to have a cartesian coordinate system with units in meters. Then the buffering becomes straightforward.

Comment: Agreed! if you want km (or meters, or feet) buffers then project to a coordinate system that uses that unit (or derived unit - metres for km) then project back, trying to guess how many radians, degrees, minutes etc.. a projected unit is will be *wrong* or at least inaccurate.